# VBE of BJT keeps increasing beyond 0.7V, Why is it not getting saturated around 0.7V?

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, analog, bjt, bias

Background: I am trying to understand the progressive steps to the final current limiter mentioned in this [site](https://www.radiolocman.com/shem/schematics.html?di=113034).

1. As a first step, I am checking the effect without the feedback loop:

[image]

Why is the VBE not maintained around 0.7V? The base current is also getting quite high(mA) due to the VBE overdrive.

I know the device might be damaged, but my doubt is what is the exact condition for ensuring VBE settles to around 0.7V.

2. I had tried replacing the BJT with a diode and it gets settled to 0.7V correctly:

   [image: enter code here]

**In both cases the forward biased PN junction current varies from 0-2mA.
Why does it cause significant change in VBE in transistor case but less variation in diode case?**

Comment: The current gets way too large for the BC546. Its max continues current is 100mA. The voltage as well, the max is 65V. Not to mention the power that gets dissipated in the transistor. Try this, 12V supply and 10mA current. As a side note, the current gain of a transistor is very dependent on a lot of factors. Without feedback this will never be stable.

Comment: @BasVisscher: Edited the question to understand the difference between PN junctions in diode and BJT

Comment: IC in your first example is still 7.7 times larger than the absolute maximum rating. If you were to build this circuit, your transistor will explode. In case of your second schematic, here the current is a lovely 2mA. That is well within the operation limits of most generic diodes. If you want to compare them, replace the diode in the 2nd schematic for a transistor. Don't connect the collector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are operating Q2 beyond its limits. You can't expect its base-emitter voltage stay less than 1V whilst its collector-emitter voltage goes 200V.

In the simulator, the transistor is modelled based on these operational limits. If you put a transistor having a max collector-emitter voltage of close to 200V you'll get less than 1V of base-emitter drop.

> In both cases the forward biased PN junction current varies from 0-2mA. Why does it cause significant change in VBE in transistor case but less variation in diode case?

You are comparing an individual diode to a BJT's base-emitter junction. Disconnect Q2's collector from the voltage source and try again. You'll get what I mean.